# pygame draw lifebar with a clipping area

Tags: pygame

I'd like to draw a lifebar with pygame by using a clipping area (limit the area to a half when half of the hitpoints are gone for example.)
But even though the clipping area is correct, I always get the full image.

That's my lifebar class:

```
class Lifebar():
    def __init__(self,x,y,images,owner):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.images=images
        self.owner=owner
        self.owner.world.game.addGUI(self)
        self.inter=False

    def getValues(self):
        value1 = 1.0 * self.owner.hitpoints
        value2 = 1.0 * self.owner.maxhitpoints
        return [value1,value2]

    def render(self,surface):
        rendervalues = self.getValues()
        maxwidth = self.images[0].get_width()
        ratio = rendervalues[0] / rendervalues[1]
        actwidth = int(round(maxwidth * ratio))
        surface.blit(self.images[0],(self.x,self.y))
        surface.set_clip(self.x, 0, (self.x+actwidth), 1080)
        surface.blit(self.images[1],(self.x,self.y))
        self.owner.world.game.setclipDefault()
        surface.blit(self.images[2],(self.x,self.y))
```

I checked that the hitpoints weren't full and that the clipping area was limited in x direction. (get_clip())
I don't know if I misunderstood how set_clip() works because I only used it for the whole screen before(objects that were partially out of the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.set_clip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip) method of a `pygame.Surface` object **sets the area in which any other surfaces will be drawn into** when you call `.blit()`. This means that the passed rectangle *defines* a new point of origin on the destination surface as well as the size of the area which will be updated.

To **cut out a specific area of an image and draw it onto a surface** you could pass an optional rectangle as third parameter to the [`.blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method:

```
surface.blit(source_image, #source image (surface) which you want to cut out
             (destination_x, destination_y), #coordinates on the destination surface
             (x_coordinate, y_coordinate, width, height)) #"cut out"-rect
```

I hope this helps you a little bit :)

Comment: Does this mean that I need to use x=0 for the blitting when the clipping area starts where the life bar starts?

Comment: Haven't had the time to do a lot of python recently, but I just tried and it works perfectly. Thanks.